# WFS GetFeature control doesn't take 'viewparams' into account

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I use GeoServer to get my WMS data. Everything works great for showing data in OpenLayers.

GeoServer has the ability to create SQL views and use parameters to return certain geometry. These parameters are called viewparams. This could be an example of a SQL view:

```
select *
from myTable
where age = %ageParam%
```

When using viewparams you are able to pass the value for the 'ageParam' parameter. If a parameter is not set, a predefined default value will be used. More information about this topic can be found [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/sqlview.html#creating-a-parametric-sql-view).

In OpenLayers however,  "getFeature" control does not take the 'viewparams' parameter into account. This means it always returns features with the default parameter values.

Is this a bug, a missing feature or something I just missed.

**Edit 1**

Here is a screencast I made to visualise the problem.

http://screencast.com/t/RgrQvaoyoqz

As you can see, the layer is redrawn with new points but the selectFeature control still returns the old features.

**Edit 2**

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<wfs:Query typeName="test:point_query" xmlns:test="http://test.boedy.p:8080/wms">
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
<ogc:BBOX>
<ogc:PropertyName>geometry</ogc:PropertyName>
<gml:Envelope xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<gml:lowerCorner>490488.82657346 6800062.1058854</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>491071.65891403 6800556.5579121</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>
</ogc:BBOX>
</ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

**edit **

This is the JavaScript code for the layer and controller

```
test = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("test",
    "http://test.boedy.p:8080/wms", 
    {
        'layers': 'test:test_query',
        viewparams: 'x:'+myX+';y:'+myY,
        maxfeatures: 2000,
        ratio: 1,
        transparent: true,
        isBaseLayer: false}
    );

selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature(
        {
            protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(test),
            clickout: true, toggle: false,
            multiple: false, hover: false,
            box: true,
            toggleKey: "shiftKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
            multipleKey: "shiftKey",
            eventListeners: {
                featureselected: onFeatureSelect,
                featureunselected: onFeatureUnselect
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: can you post an example url?

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.

Comment: @iant I can't give you an example url, because It's still in development and only locally accessible. I've added a short video displaying the problem instead. I hope that's of some use.

Comment: I meant could you post an example of the URL that is being sent by the client (preferably to a default layer) so we can try to reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: @iant Edit2 displays the payload. I'm not sure if that's the URL you were talking about.

Comment: OK I can't see any view parameters in your request so I think you have a client problem not a geoserver problem.

Comment: @iant Yes, I thought that would be the case. I forgot to mention I was using openlayers for the client. It has a function that get the features. I'm not sure if this function is able to pass view parameters..

Comment: in that case we will need to see some (all?) of the JavaScript code. Also can you clarify exactly what you mean by view parameters?

Comment: @iant I'm not at liberty to show all code, but I've added the code that effects the layer and the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS.js) of the [WFS.fromWMSLayer](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS-js.html#OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer) function, it looks like you should pass in your viewparams as an additional option:

```
        protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(test, 
                                                       {viewparams: 'x:'+myX+';y:'+myY}),
```

Check the URL that is called when you select a feature - and hopefully the viewparams will be added to the URL.

If you wanted to apply a filter to a WFS layer you can play around with the filter code and the XML it generates on [this demo](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/filter.html).

Once you have the filter code correct then set the WFS layer's filter [filter](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.filter) property.

```
        wfsLayer.filter = my_filter;
```

As you don't have a WFS layer you could try the following - the parameters may be copied across - you'd have to test.

```
        protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(test, 
                                                       {filter: my_filter}),
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm doubting if this is possible in openlayers or with the WFS protocol at all.  I was able to get viewparams working with WMS, but not with WFS.

Comment: To clarify - the viewparams need to be sent as part of the URL or as part of the OGC Filter XML for it to work correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm guessing it should be a part of the payload/OGC Filter. Geoserver suggests it's possible with WFS, but doesn't give an example on it's usage.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should switch to filters? So instead of filtering via sql use an openlayers filter?

Comment: An OL filter is simply XML that is sent to the server where the actual filtering occurs. OL itself doesn't filter the features.

Comment: Ok, I've been fiddeling with the code for the last hour to get this to work, without any succes! I now use an OL filter, since I might as well. I can't get the filter to work for the getFeature control though.

Comment: I'm now using a temporary solution by looping all features and their data. I'm guessing this is not very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Using the WMSGetFeatureInfo method, the way to pass along **viewparams** is 
by using

- **vendorparams** and
- and assigning the viewparams in the eventlistener before the callback function retrieving the "click result" from the WMS layer

  ```
  click_info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
      title: 'Identify features by clicking',
      layers: queryableMapLayers,
      infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
      queryVisible: true,
      autoActivate: true,
      eventListeners: {
          beforegetfeatureinfo: function(event) { 
          this.vendorParams = { viewparams: "word:"+startWord}; 
          }, 
          getfeatureinfo: function(e) {
              var items = [];
              Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {
                  items.push({
                      xtype: "propertygrid",
                      title: feature.attributes.text,
                  });
              });
              console.log(items[0]);
              new GeoExt.Popup({
                  title: "Feature Info",
                  width: 200,
                  height: 300,
                  layout: "accordion",
                  autoscroll: true,
                  map: viewPort.mapPanel.map,
                  location: viewPort.mapPanel.map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy),
                  items: items
              }).show();

          }
      }
  });
  ```

Thanks to [this post](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/update-vendorParams-for-WMSGetFeatureInfo-td3921034.html)!